# Object references are lost but the resources held are retained

Tags: c#

```
IndentedTextWriter tw = new IndentedTextWriter(internalTW, "    ");
```

Object referenced by 'tw' is lost, but related resources are not disposed here "TW " is a text writer where internalTW is a  TextWriter

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);
```

object referenced by 'cmd' is lost, but related resources are not disposed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
using (IndentedTextWriter tw = new IndentedTextWriter(internalTW, "    ")) {
  // use it here
}
```

resp.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con)) {
  // use it here
}
```

At the end of the `using` block, `Dispose()` is called on the objects and the resources should be freed...

Answer (score 3):

The types all implement `IDisposable`, and thus **it is the caller's responsibility** to call `Dispose()` like e.g.

```
using(var tw = new IndentedTextWriter(internalTW, "    ")) {
    // do something with tw
}
```

or by explicitly calling `Dispose()` in a `finally` block.